# Rclone mount shared between containers in the same K8s pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes, mount, rclone

In my k8s pod, I want to give a container access to a S3 bucket, mounted with rclone.

Now, the container running rclone needs to run with `--privileged`, which is a problem for me, since my `main-container` will run user code which I have no control of and can be potentially harmful to my Pod.

The solution I’m trying now is to have a `sidecar-container` just for the task of running rclone, mounting S3 in a `/shared_storage` folder, and sharing this folder with the `main-container` through a Volume `shared-storage`. This is a simplified pod.yml file:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: two-containers
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never

  volumes:
    - name: shared-storage
      emptyDir: {}

  containers:
    - name: main-container
      image: busybox
      command: ["sh", "-c", "sleep 1h"]
      volumeMounts:
        - name: shared-storage
          mountPath: /shared_storage
          # mountPropagation: HostToContainer

    - name: sidecar-container
      image: mycustomsidecarimage
      securityContext:
        privileged: true
      command: ["/bin/bash"]
      args: ["-c", "python mount_source.py"]
      env:
        - name: credentials
          value: XXXXXXXXXXX
      volumeMounts:
        - name: shared-storage
          mountPath: /shared_storage
          mountPropagation: Bidirectional
```

The pod runs fine and from `sidecar-container` I can read, create and delete files from my S3 bucket.
But from `main-container` no files are listed inside of `shared_storage`. I can create files (if I set `readOnly: false`) but those do not appear in `sidecar-container`.

If I don’t run the rclone mount to that folder, the containers are able to share files again. So that tells me that is something about the rclone process not letting `main-container` read from it.

In `mount_source.py` I am running rclone with `--allow-other` and I have edit `etc/fuse.conf`  as suggested [here](https://github.com/rclone/rclone/issues/811#issuecomment-255599253).

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't this this is going to work; I think mount namespaces in containers are set up so that mounts in one container aren't going to be visible in other containers.

Comment: are you aware of any workarounds for this limitation which wouldn't involve giving root privileges to `main-container`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to make it work by using:

- `mountPropagation: HostToContainer` on `main-container`
- `mountPropagation: Bidirectional` on `sidecar-container`

I can control read/write permissions to specific mounts using `readOnly: true/false` on `main-container`. This is of course also possible to set within `rclone mount` command.

Now the `main-container` does not need to run in privileged mode and my users code can have access to their s3 buckets through those mount points!

Interestingly, it doesn't seem to work if I set `volumeMount:mountPath` to be a sub-folder of the rclone mounted path. So if I want to grant `main-container` different read/write permissions to different subpaths, I had to create a separate `rclone mount` for each sub-folder.

I'm not 100% sure if there's any extra security concerns with that approach though.